# People in a white room in space shrinking

Tags: story-identification

So I watched this movie when I was younger (early 2000, I guess) and the only thing I remember is this one scene.

There were some people exploring the space and somehow they ended up in this white room and they shrank and in they were looking for someone in this form. And that's it and I am not even sure on the shrinking part, hah. But the white room/space stuck in my head.

Comment: It's not Willy Wonka's Chocolate Factory is it?

Comment: Do you have a feeling for the era of the film?  50s?  70s?  90s?

Comment: The movie had The Fifth Elemend kind of vibe and the movie was probably from the era of the 90s. Dunno for sure.

Comment: Are you thinking of 'innerspace'? 
While the good guys shrinking facility is very low tech, the bad guys one is pristine white and has a exoskeleton that looks like a space suit. At about the 1:00 mark you can see a brief clip of the space looking room https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLAbTbGQcr8

Comment: I've looked at it but I don't think the movie was comidic. It had a more serious feel to it.

Comment: There's a scene like this in an old movie call "Star Wars."

Comment: I watched all Star Wars movies, so I would know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be the scene from 2000's [Mission to Mars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0183523/), when the three space-suited astronauts enter the Face on Mars? It's an all-white room, and when the door closes it kind of looks like they're shrinking:

[image]

See the Mission to Mars movie trailer, starting at the 1:46 mark

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are thinking of the movie 'innerspace'. Although it takes place on earth, it does involve some imagery that is similar to what you would see in space based science fiction.

Notably, it has a scene where several characters are shrunk by about 60% in a white room near an exoskeleton that looks like a space suit, but then attempt to still carry out their plans while miniturized to some humorous results.

A brief shot of the room is at the 1min mark here.

A fairly entertaining movie by the guy who made Gremlins.

Comment: Nope, that's not the one. It wasn't a comedy, huh. But thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it was Cube 2: Hypercube. White rooms, some shifting, not a comedy. All of the rooms were white. Movie came out in 2002.

See the trailer:

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Tom, could it be [the Mike Teevee scene from Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fj3WBfRZ5Nc)?

Comment: I was mostly joking, but it's possible someone could mis-remember this scene to be in space

Comment: Uh, no, all the people in the scene were older. In space suits and stuff, hahah. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It's not Fantastic Voyage is it? A team of doctors are miniaturised in a submarine and injected into a scientist to remove a blood-clot in his brain. They wore protective suits, a bit like space-suits.

Comment: Here's a [trailer for Fantastic Voyage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3o8vsU0Dw-4).

Comment: Nope, not the one.